# How to resize HighChartAnnotation @ Runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

Here is a code for storing annotation in highchart I want to do something like this but for resize my runtime added SVG Annotation.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
storeAnnotation: function(event, annotation, chart) {

                                        if(!chart.annotationDraging) {
                                            event.stopPropagation();
                                            event.preventDefault();
                                        }
                        if((!isOldIE && event.button === 0) || (isOldIE && event.button === 1)) {
                                            var posX = event.pageX,
                                                    posY = event.pageY;
                                            chart.activeAnnotation = annotation;
                                            chart.activeAnnotation.startX = posX;
                                            chart.activeAnnotation.startY = posY;
                                            chart.activeAnnotation.transX = 0; 
                                            chart.activeAnnotation.transY = 0; 
                                            //translateAnnotation(event);
                                            addEvent(document, 'mousemove', function(e){
                                                    annotation.events.translateAnnotation(e, chart);
                                            });
                                            //addEvent(chart.container, 'mouseleave', releaseAnnotation); TO BE OR NOT TO BE?
                                        }

                }
```

Comment: Which plugin to annotation do you have? Any live demo?

Comment: I am using "http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations" this plug in

Comment: what should be resized, have you any live demo of that ?

Comment: I want to resize element like path ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 228, 32, 'L', 228, 52, 'L', 0, 20, 'Z'] @ runtime

Comment: So you need to update this path, by setting new values for M and L parameters.

Comment: Yes its working thanks for help. Actually i want to do it on some events like mouse drag, key press and click these why i was facing problem in it.